# How to use the Elements module to make $form['element'] = array( '#type' => 'number' );

Tags: 7, forms

As Drupal 7, core field doesn't support HTML 5 form elements.

How can I use the Elements module from Form API to make the it works below?

```
$form['element'] = array(   '#type' => 'number' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a quick look at the [code of the elements module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/elements/tree/elements.module).

The number field is defined like this:

```
  $types['numberfield'] = array(
    '#input' => TRUE,
    '#step' => 1,
    '#process' => array('ajax_process_form'),
    '#element_validate' => array('elements_validate_number'),
    '#theme' => 'numberfield',
    '#theme_wrappers' => array('form_element'),
  );
```

So you should use `'#type' => 'numberfield'` instead.

Comment: Thanks for replaying me, I figured out why wasn't working at first try. It needs to turn off current module and turn on it, to trigger the hook works.

Comment: Normally clearing the cache should work too (and is faster).